# Why is the Python .readlines() method seemingly erasing a file?

Tags: python, file, save

I am trying to create a to-do list application, and to store the users tasks, I'm writing them by line to a plaintext file. At multiple points I "sync" it by calling `foo.readlines()`, but even if I hand write test data into the file, the list returns empty and the contents of the plain text file are erased.

I tried opening the file manually and writing to it and saving it, but after running the script, it is again empty and the list returns empty.

```
import numpy as np

file = open('./data.txt', 'w+')
tasks = file.readlines()

print(tasks)

#writes list to a file
def writeFile(tasks):
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        for listitem in tasks:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the file in `write` mode with "w+" at line 3. That deletes the file's contents.

You probably meant to use "r" instead of "w" in

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
```

Comment: Hi, I wasn't aware that opening in write deletes the contents! Thanks!

Comment: The fopen man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) says:      w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
              not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is
              positioned at the beginning of the file.

Comment: But the python `open` doc doesn't mention the `+` modes so it is a bit deficient.

Comment: This is part correct. Opening with "w+" should NOT delete the file contents. But I believe opening the file this way puts the cursor at the end of the file, so an attempt to read lines yields nothing. Hence, tasks is empty. Then opening the file later in just "w" mode erases its contents.

Also, before you print tasks, you ought to close the file with file.close()

Comment: As I note above, the linux man page says that "w+" truncates the file if it exists. You may be thinking of "a" (append) mode.

Comment: @GaryO You are correct. I forgot "a" is dedicated for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

'Read' mode is the default mode if none specified

```
file = open('data.txt')
```

Opening a file in 'Read' mode

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
```

Opening a file in 'Write' mode (will overwrite the contents of the file if exists)

```
file = open('data.txt', 'w')
```

Opening a file in 'Append' mode (will append to the existing file without overwriting)

```
file = open('data.txt', 'a')
```